# Chess performance and IQ

Tags: intelligence, iq, chess

Are there formal studies relating chess performance (e.g. [ELO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)) and IQ? I found a proposed [Levitt equation](http://www.jlevitt.dircon.co.uk/iq.htm) (also mentioned in [thechessworld](https://thechessworld.com/articles/healthpsycology/chess-rating-and-iq-score-correlation/)):

`Elo ~ (10 x IQ) + 1000`

Is there some systematic evidence to back this formula, and/or propose a better one, and how well do such regressions fit, i.e. what's their goodness of fit (R), or alternatively stating this last part: how well does ELO (or some equivalent measure) correlate with IQ?

**Regarding the question linked: this one is not even remotely a duplicate. The other question asks if playing chess can *improve* IQ. (and the answer seems to be no.) None of the answers there even talk how much IQ affect chess performance. The answer to my question is a qualified yes, by the way. Just think of the limit case where IQ were "set at birth", and your chess performance depended 100% just on IQ. You could still play chess all day and your IQ wouldn't change.**

Comment: Didn't take me long find a good study: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/09/160913124722.htm I'll summarize it  later if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15764/7001

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chess to enhance human cognitive abilities?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15764/chess-to-enhance-human-cognitive-abilities)

Comment: @ChrisRogers: read that other question carefully. This is not even remotely a duplicate.

Comment: **Why should chess improve your intellect?** is to me the same as **Are there formal studies relating chess performance and IQ?**

Comment: @ChrisRogers It's two separate questions to ask: (1) Does chess training *improve* cognitive performance? (2) Does high cognitive ability result in better chess playing? Two quite separate questions to tackle.